# Найти индексы минимальных элементов в столбцах матрицы расстояний, исключая элементы главной диагонали и строки с индексам уже найденных элементов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, генераторы

DF:

```
  1  2  3  4  5  KEY
1  0 65 95 80 49  11
2 65  0 78 69 16   9
3 95 78  0 55 88   6
4 80 69 55  0 87  18
5 49 16 88 87  0   2
```

Имеем таблицу условных расстояний между пунктами. Имеем ключ. Необходимо получить:

1. Определить индекс (point_а) с наименьшим значением расстояния от пункта 2 (столбца) поделенного на KEY.
2. Определить индекс (point_b) с наименьшим значением расстояния от point_a поделенного на KEY, исключая предыдущие пункты.
3. Определить дальнейшие индексы по аналогии с point_b с применением генератора.

Моя попытка:

```
exept0_a = df[2] != 0
point_a = (df.loc[exept0_a, 2] / df.loc[exept0_a, 'KEY']).idxmin()
exept0_b = (df[point_a] != 0) & ~df.index.isin([point_a])
point_b = (df.loc[exept0_b, point_a] / df.loc[exept0_b, 'KEY']).idxmin()
exept0_c = (df[point_b] != 0) & ~df.index.isin([point_a, point_b])
point_c = (df.loc[exept0_c, point_b] / df.loc[exept0_c, 'KEY']).idxmin()
```

Касательно генератора идей нет. Прошу помощи сообщества
Хочу получить:

```
list = [point_a, point_b, point_c]
[4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74965/discussion-on-question-by-python42------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала получим матрицу расстояний с учетом деления на коэффициент `KEY`, а также заменим нули в главной диагонали на бесконечность (`np.inf`):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = df.drop('KEY',1).div(df['KEY'], axis=0)
d.values[np.diag_indices_from(d)] = np.inf
```

Получим:

```
In [42]: d
Out[42]:
           1          2          3          4          5
1        inf   5.909091   8.636364   7.272727   4.454545
2   7.222222        inf   8.666667   7.666667   1.777778
3  15.833333  13.000000        inf   9.166667  14.666667
4   4.444444   3.833333   3.055556        inf   4.833333
5  24.500000   8.000000  44.000000  43.500000        inf
```

Список для хранения результатов:

```
res = []
```

Функция для нахождения индекса минимального элемента, исключая строки со значениями индекса найденных ранее элементов

```
def f(col):
    ret = col.loc[~col.index.isin(res)].idxmin()
    if ret not in res:
        res.append(ret)
```

применяем функцию ко всем столбцам:

```
_ = d.apply(f)
```

результат:

```
print(res)
```

выдает:

```
[4, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

получить первые три элемента результирующего списка:

```
print(res[:3])

# [4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Надеюсь так стало более понятно. Суть в том, что каждая последующая переменная ссылается на предыдущую. В моем коде они прописаны, но есть подозрение, что Python способен создавать их автоматически

Comment: не могу сообразить в каком месте определено, что поиск минимального значения необходимо начинать в колонке (столбце) "2"?

Comment: @Python42, поиск начинается в первом столбце

Comment: просто в вопросе акцент на том, чтобы отыскать в столбце "2". Суть в том, чтобы начальный столбец для поиска можно было задать

Comment: `d.iloc[:, 1:]` - срез DF, начинающийся со второго столбца...

Comment: я в вопросе увидел акцент на то, чтобы начать со второго пункта, а не со второго столбца, поэтому я заполнил главную диагональ бесконечностью. В первом столбце мы находим минимальное расстояние между первым пунктом и остальными и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

По сути вам подойдут просто списки. Сначала перепишем через индексы списка:

```
exept0[0] = df[2] != 0
point[0] = (df.loc[exept0[0], 2] / df.loc[exept0[0], 'KEY']).idxmin()

exept0[1] = (df[point[0]] != 0) & ~df.index.isin([point[0]])
point[1] = (df.loc[exept0[1], point[0]] / df.loc[exept0[1], 'KEY']).idxmin()

exept0[2] = (df[point[1]] != 0) & ~df.index.isin([point[0], point[1]])
point[2] = (df.loc[exept0[2], point[1]] / df.loc[exept0[2], 'KEY']).idxmin()
```

Перепишем через добавление элементов в список с помощью `append`, и частично заменим индексы на относительные (с конца списка):

```
exept0 = []
point = []

exept0.append(df[2] != 0)
point.append((df.loc[exept0[0], 2] / df.loc[exept0[-1], 'KEY']).idxmin())

exept0.append((df[point[-1]] != 0) & ~df.index.isin([point[0]]))
point.append((df.loc[exept0[-1], point[-1]] / df.loc[exept0[-1], 'KEY']).idxmin())

exept0.append((df[point[-1]] != 0) & ~df.index.isin([point[0], point[1]]))
point.append((df.loc[exept0[-1], point[-1]] / df.loc[exept0[-1], 'KEY']).idxmin())
```

Дальше заметим, что кусок `[point[0], point[1], ... point[n]]` - это на самом деле сам список `point`:

```
exept0 = []
point = []

exept0.append(df[2] != 0)
point.append((df.loc[exept0[0], 2] / df.loc[exept0[-1], 'KEY']).idxmin())

exept0.append((df[point[-1]] != 0) & ~df.index.isin(point))
point.append((df.loc[exept0[-1], point[-1]] / df.loc[exept0[-1], 'KEY']).idxmin())

exept0.append((df[point[-1]] != 0) & ~df.index.isin(point))
point.append((df.loc[exept0[-1], point[-1]] / df.loc[exept0[-1], 'KEY']).idxmin())
```

Тут внезапно оказывается, что последние два этапа идентичны. Значит можно просто обернуть в цикл.

```
# Нулевой этап объединили с инициализацией
exept0 = [df[2] != 0]
point = [(df.loc[exept0[0], 2] / df.loc[exept0[-1], 'KEY']).idxmin()]

# Остались этапы от 1 до n
for i in range(1, n):
    exept0.append((df[point[-1]] != 0) & ~df.index.isin(point))
    point.append((df.loc[exept0[-1], point[-1]] / df.loc[exept0[-1], 'KEY']).idxmin())

# На выходе списки длиной n
```