# Переменная в имени переменной Python

Tags: python, переменные

Возможно ли определение следующей переменной:

str_i, где i - также является переменной?

Comment: Даже если и возможно — зачем?

Comment: Что-бы ответить на вопрос, заданный ранее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/802652/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-python

Comment: Я там тоже хотел спросить, но поленился просто — зачем?) Впрочем, в комментариях там и без меня объяснили, что это всё не нужно

Comment: такие вещи как `exec()`, `globals()`, `setattr(mod, name, x)` очень редко следует использовать. Практически наверняка, чтобы вы не делали, есть лучше для конкретной задачи решение нежели exec вызов. К примеру, почему вы не хотите [`points` список использовать вместо point1, point2, point3, etc переменных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/802652/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-python#comment1269223_802652)? Старайтесь вопросы самодостаточными делать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам требуется создать переменную по строковому значению лексемы:

```
i = 'vars'
# магия
print(str_vars)
```

В качестве магии можно использовать [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
exec('str_%s = 123' % i)
```

Полностью код:

```
i = 'vars'
exec('str_%s = 123' % i)
print(str_vars)
```

Определение переменной обязательно

Comment: Спасибо. exec по сути вызывает(ссылается на) переменную, но не определяет ее. Есть ли что-то на подобии следующего: exec('str_%s = 123' % i) = 25?

Comment: ``exec`` не вызывает переменную и не ссылается. ``exec`` строит из аргументов строку, а дальше она обрабатывается как самый обычный код. В данном случае на выходе из ``exec`` получается ``str_vars = 123``. После вашего ``exec('str_%s = 123' % i) = 25`` получится ``str_vars = 123 = 25`` что приведет к "инвалид синтакс".

Answer (score 4):

Можно и без `eval` обойтись:

```
for i in range(6):
    globals()['num_%s' % i] = i ** 2

print(num_1)  # 1
print(num_2)  # 4
print(num_3)  # 9
print(num_4)  # 16
print(num_5)  # 25
```

---

**PS.**

Но лучше не играться с глобальными переменными, т.к. можно случайно поменять значение тем, что были. Лучше в таких случаях складывать в словарь:

```
d = dict()
for i in range(6):
    d['num_%s' % i] = i ** 2

print(d['num_5'])
```

Тоже самое, но с рефакторингом (python3):

```
d = {f'num_{i}': i ** 2 for i in range(6)}
print(d['num_5'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам **не нужно** использовать "переменную в имени переменной". Вместо этого вам нужны просто списки. К примеру:

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c']
i = 2
print(s[i])  # c
```

Использовать `exec` и `eval` без особой необходимости - обычно плохая идея.

В вашем предыдущем вопросе я также [дал ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803210/1365), как реализовать через списки.

Answer (score 2):

```
name = "str_"
for n in range (5):
    exec(name + "%s = %d" % (n,n))
```

На выходе будет пять переменных `str_0` до `str_4` со значениями от 0 до 4.

Как оно работает:
`exec` строит из аргументов строку (как `print`), а дальше эта строка обрабатывается как самый обычный код. В данном случае вместо переменных подставляются их значения и получается в первой итерации

```
str_0 = 0
```

во второй

```
str_1 = 1
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
###Описание проблемы:
#Введите целое число (выбран ввод пользователем для примера, 
#чтобы показать что "x" заранее неизвестно)

    x = input("Введите число 1, 2 или 3:  >>  ")

#В зависимости от ввода пользователя результатом будет соответствующий список

    list_1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
    list_2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']
    list_3 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']

    if x == "1":
        res = list_1
    elif x == "2":
        res = list_2
    elif x == "3":
        res = list_3
    print(res)

#В ходе более гибкого решения (велосипеда) ТС задал Вам вопрос. 
#Готов снести если не прав.
#Все что нужно было, при условии что заранее известны связки 
#(переменной x и списком), создать обычный словарь:

    my_dict = {
        "1": ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
        "2": ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'],
        "3": ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
    }

    print(my_dict.get(x))
```

Comment: Для числовых (по сути) индексов не нужен словарь: https://ideone.com/QhJ1cc

Comment: Не важно что использовать в качестве контейнера dict или list, я показал что проблема у ТС на этапе проектирования и решается ранним связыванием