# Переменные в названии

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если требуется добавлять данные в определенный список из множества похожих (например, list1, list2, list3), то хотелось бы делать это через переменную.

Что-то похожее на: если a = 2 то list2, при a = 3 , будет ссылка на list3

Таких списков очень много и данных так же много. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переменная в имени переменной Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803093/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-python). Но это не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: Правильный ответ - сделать список списков, обращаться к подспискам по индексу.